# Returning from tkinter toplevel button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter GUI in which a user needs to authenticate against some system. When a user clicks RUN, an authentication Toplevel pops, wherein the user enters credentials, clicks OK, and the application creates a connection instance from those credentials.

The difficulty I am having is in passing back that connection instance and not having the application proceed before it is successfully returned. Here is an extremely simplified code snippet that shows the general layout.

```
import tkinter as tk

def log_in():
    def click_ok():
        username = usr_entry_var.get()
        password = pwd_entry_var.get()

        # This is the portion that creates a connection instance
        # that I desire to later perform actions against in the
        # form of connection.doStuff()
        # I have just set it to some text here for brevity, as this
        # portion is working fine.
        connection = 'someStuffThatAuthenticates'

        login.destroy()

    login = tk.Toplevel()

    usr_lbl = tk.Label(login, text='Username:')
    usr_lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    usr_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
    usr_entry = tk.Entry(login, width=40, textvariable=usr_entry_var)
    usr_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)

    pwd_lbl = tk.Label(login, text='Password:')
    pwd_lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)

    pwd_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
    pwd_entry = tk.Entry(login, width=40, textvariable=pwd_entry_var)
    pwd_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    ok_btn = tk.Button(login, text='OK', command=click_ok)
    ok_btn.grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=2)

def click_run():
    connection = log_in()

    # Here is where I perform actions against the returned connection instance.
    # I am just printing it here for brevity.
    print(str(connection))

root = tk.Tk()

run_btn = tk.Button(root, text='RUN', command=click_run)
run_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The results I get from the above is that as soon as I click the RUN button on root, the code `print()`s None at the same time the login screen pops. I've tried quite a few things to get the code to

A) return `connection` successfully and

B) wait until it is returned before attempting to use it

Rather than list out my feeble attempts, I just left the code here simple.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to solve this is to use tkinter's `wait_window` or `wait_variable` methods. The first will not return until the target window has been destroyed (typical for a modal dialog), and `wait_variable` will not return until a variable has been set (common with non-modal dialogs)

While the program is waiting, it is still able to process events.

effbot.org has a nice concise write-up on creating dialogs: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm